# Java swing multilanguage app

Tags: java, swing, multilingual

I am developing a point of sale desktop app in English for forms.

I want to add Arabic language: the user can switch from one language to another.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Java supports internationalization out of the box, please see [Internationalization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/) tutorial. Roughly, you should

1. Move all UI-related messages to separate *.properties files
2. Create separate *.properties file for every supported language
3. Resolve required messages file by Locale (language)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help I will follow internationalisation article